# Applying generic CSS style to only a single container

Tags: html, css

I wanted to apply the CSS style defined in Style Tag inside Head Tag to be applied only to a particular div. Sample HTML

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      p {
        font-size:10pt;
        color:blue;
        background-color:green;
      }
      span {
        font-size:16pt;
        color:green;
        background-color:yellow;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="div1">
      <p style = "font-size:14pt;">Hello world</p>
      <p>How Are You</p>
      <span>How Are You Test span</span>
      <div>How Are You Test div </div>
    </div>

    <div class="div2">
      <p>This is div2</p>
      <p style = "font-size:14pt;">Hello world</p>
      <p>How Are You</p>
      <span>How Are You Test span</span>
      <div>How Are You Test div </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I wanted to add the styles only to `div2`. Instead of defining each style with `div.div2 > p` & `div.div2 > span`, I want to apply the styles altogether. Is there any way to do that?

Something like: `div.div2 > p {}, span{}` etc... so that all the styles defined will be applied to `div` tag with class name `div2`.

Comment: Yes, and it's done exactly as you described (`div.div2 > p {...}`). A quick search on "CSS selectors" will help you.

Comment: But for me, i am receiving this css style like p{ .. } span {...} div{...}. i want to keep all these inside a single div.div2

Comment: @krish, there is, see my answer

Comment: @TheChamp : The op asked to do with native css though there is no scss tag with the question, so there is no way to do that in css.

Comment: @VeenaSujith : There is no such possibility to do like that.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
div.div2 > p, div.div2 span {
    ...
}
```

Comment: i dont want to do it individually for all the tags. Is there any way to do it together. Separate styles are applied to each tags.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you take a look at [scss](http://sass-lang.com/guide#topic-3), which would turn this code

```
div.div2 > p {
  font-size:10pt;
  color:blue;
  background-color:green;
}

div.div2 > span {
  font-size:16pt;
  color:green;
  background-color:yellow;
}
```

into

```
div.div2 {
  p {
    font-size:10pt;
    color:blue;
    background-color:green;
  }

  span {
    font-size:16pt;
    color:green;
    background-color:yellow;
  }
}
```

It makes nesting allot easier, you don't have to define `div.div2` multiple times. It will save you allot of time & trouble

Comment: Actually i recieved some style information, and i want to apply it only to a particular div tag. i tried to define it like div.div2 {
  p {
    font-size:10pt;
    color:blue;
    background-color:green;
  }

  span {
    font-size:16pt;
    color:green;
    background-color:yellow;
  }
} but not working, how to use SCSS ??